# How to fix Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC for wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have got an error message for custom payment wordpress plugin when processing the payment such as:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC in
>   /home/galer258/public_html/dev/wp-content/plugins/bcasakuku/result.php
>   on line 3

or please check out [this link](http://dev.galerigadget.com/wp-content/plugins/bcasakuku/result.php) for further info.

**Here result.php script**

```
<?php

public function doPayment(){

    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), 1);
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ){
        if( isset( $_POST['MerchantID'] ) AND isset( $_POST['TransactionID'] ) AND isset( $_POST['TransactionReffID'] ) AND isset( $_POST['Signature'] ) ){

            //VALIDATE MERCHANT ID
            if( $_POST['MerchantID'] ==  $_POST['MerchantID'] ){

                $orders = $_POST['TransactionID'];
                if( $orders AND is_numeric( $_POST['TransactionID'] ) ){

                    if( $orders['order_status_id'] == $this->$_POST['TransactionID'] {

                        $sakukuOrder = $_POST['TransactionID'];
                        if( $sakukuOrder ){
                            $str =  $sakukuOrder['AccToken'].$sakukuOrder['TransactionID'].$sakukuOrder['Amount'].$sakukuOrder['PaymentID'];
                            $validate = strtoupper( hash('sha256', $str) );

                            if( $_POST['Signature'] == $validate ){
                                $this->$sakukuOrder['TransactionID'], 5;
                                $this->generateOutput( 0, "00" );
                            }else{
                                $this->generateOutput( 1, "01" );
                            }

                        }else{
                            $this->generateOutput( 1, "01" );
                        }
                    }else{
                        $this->generateOutput( 2, "01" );
                    }           

                }else{
                    $this->generateOutput( 1, "01" );
                }
            }else{
                $this->generateOutput( 1, "01" );
            }

        }else{
            $this->generateOutput( 1, "01" );
        }
    }else{
        $this->generateOutput( 1, "01" );
    }
}

private function generateOutput( $rs, $status ){

    $reason = array(
        "Indonesian" => array("Sukses","Transaksi tidak dapat diproses.","Transaksi sudah dibayar."),
        "English" => array("Success","Transaction cannot be processed.","Transaction has been paid."),
    );

    $output = array(
            "MerchantID" => ( !isset( $_POST['MerchantID'] ) ) ? '' : $_POST['MerchantID'],
            "TransactionID" => ( !isset( $_POST['TransactionID'] ) ) ? '' : $_POST['TransactionID'],
            "FlagStatus" => "01",
            "ReasonStatus" => array( "Indonesian" => "", "English" => "" )
        );

    $output['FlagStatus'] = $status;
    $output['ReasonStatus']['Indonesian'] = $reason['Indonesian'][ $rs ];
    $output['ReasonStatus']['English'] = $reason['English'][ $rs ];
    echo json_encode($output);      
}
?>
```

You can try to buy one product [on this link](http://dev.galerigadget.com/product/samsung-galaxy-tab/) using BCA sakuku as payment option like screenshot below:

[image: BCA SAkuku Payment Option]

Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATED #1:**

**Here latest result.php script**

```
  <?php

function doPayment(){

    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), 1);
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ){
        if( isset( $_POST['MerchantID'] ) AND isset( $_POST['TransactionID'] ) AND isset( $_POST['TransactionReffID'] ) AND isset( $_POST['Signature'] ) ){

            //VALIDATE MERCHANT ID
            if( $_POST['MerchantID'] ==  $_POST['MerchantID'] ){
                $sakukuOrder = $_POST['TransactionID'];  
                $orders = $_POST['TransactionID'];
                if( $orders AND is_numeric( $_POST['TransactionID'] ) ){

                    if( $orders['order_status_id'] == $this->$_POST['TransactionID'] {


                        if( $sakukuOrder ){
                            $str =  $sakukuOrder['AccToken'].$sakukuOrder['TransactionID'].$sakukuOrder['Amount'].$sakukuOrder['PaymentID'];
                            $validate = strtoupper( hash('sha256', $str) );

                            if( $_POST['Signature'] == $validate ){
                                $this->$sakukuOrder['TransactionID'], 5;
                                $this->generateOutput( 0, "00" );
                            }else{
                                $this->generateOutput( 1, "01" );
                            }

                        }else{
                            $this->generateOutput( 1, "01" );
                        }
                    }else{
                        $this->generateOutput( 2, "01" );
                    }           

                }else{
                    $this->generateOutput( 1, "01" );
                }
            }else{
                $this->generateOutput( 1, "01" );
            }

        }else{
            $this->generateOutput( 1, "01" );
        }
    }else{
        $this->generateOutput( 1, "01" );
    }
}

private function generateOutput( $rs, $status ){

    $reason = array(
        "Indonesian" => array("Sukses","Transaksi tidak dapat diproses.","Transaksi sudah dibayar."),
        "English" => array("Success","Transaction cannot be processed.","Transaction has been paid."),
    );

    $output = array(
            "MerchantID" => ( !isset( $_POST['MerchantID'] ) ) ? '' : $_POST['MerchantID'],
            "TransactionID" => ( !isset( $_POST['TransactionID'] ) ) ? '' : $_POST['TransactionID'],
            "FlagStatus" => "01",
            "ReasonStatus" => array( "Indonesian" => "", "English" => "" )
        );

    $output['FlagStatus'] = $status;
    $output['ReasonStatus']['Indonesian'] = $reason['Indonesian'][ $rs ];
    $output['ReasonStatus']['English'] = $reason['English'][ $rs ];
    echo json_encode($output);      
}
?>
```

Got another error message such as:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in
>   /home/galer258/public_html/dev/wp-content/plugins/bcasakuku/result.php
>   on line 18

So How I can fix it?

Comment: Functions can only be declared public or private inside Classes, Interfaces or Traits.

Comment: It seems that the plugin is not correctly installed, or is not working at all. It looks incomplete. I believe that you aren't supposed to call `result.php` directly.

Comment: `if( $orders['order_status_id'] == $this->$_POST['TransactionID'] {`. You missed a closing brace.

Comment: Try to use any PHP editor in order to see what and where are you errors. NtBeans IDE is a good start. `$this->$sakukuOrder['TransactionID'], 5;` also is not valid syntax.

Comment: @MichielPater its already fixed please check out my another problem on [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36308017/php-logic-always-fails-when-generate-different-output-for-same-flag-status)

Answer (score 1):

The `public` keyword is used only in function/variable declarations from within a `class`. Since you're not using a `class` you need to remove it from your code.